# How to use jQuery 1.x instead of 2.x in Orchard 1.10?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm setting up a site using Orchard CMS 1.10 that must support at least IE 7. The jQuery used in Orchard.Modules is the 2.x branch, which doesn't support older versions of IE.

I have tried putting the 1.x version in my theme and defining it like so:

```
manifest.DefineScript("jQuery").SetUrl("jquery-1.12.2.min.js", "jquery-1.12.2.js");
```

But everything that requires jQuery still uses the 2.x version from Orchard.Resources. It's not really feasible to to rename it something like "ThemeJQuery" because there are 3rd party modules that require jQuery and I don't want to modify them.

I managed to hack it by setting a version number on the declaration and making it higher than the one in Orchard.Resources, like so:

```
manifest.DefineScript("jQuery").SetUrl("jquery-1.12.2.min.js", "jquery-1.12.2.js").SetVersion("3.0");
```

This seems to work, but that fake version number is pretty hacky. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: AFAIK that's exactly what the SetVersion Method is for. It's not about the real version of the Content.

Comment: Your question made me curious about the market share of Internet Explorer 7 and it turns out to be less than 1%. I don't doubt that there are perfectly legitimate reasons for wanting to support it but it does make me me wonder who the target audience is.

Comment: It's an internal site for the company I work for. We have many users in countries where Windows XP and old browsers are still commonplace. I ended up getting them to move the requirement to IE8, but that still requires the 1.x branch of jQuery.

I get that my situation is rare and I'm not advocating for Orchard to use jQuery 1.x. I just thought that there would be a more intuitive way of overriding resources defined in other modules. Like maybe the theme would take precedence or something.